# Filter two different structured arrays underscore js

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have two arrays:

```
array1 = [{Name: 'abc', ID: 23},{Name:'xyz', ID: 10},{Name:'def', ID: 12}];
array2 = [10,23];
```

Resultant array should be part of array 1 whose ID intersects with contents of array2.

Here, the result would be `result = [{Name: 'abc', ID: 23},{Name: 'xyz', ID:10}]`;

Any ideas how I could achieve this using underscore js?

Comment: Can you post your code so far? What didn't work? How did you attempt to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_.filter(array1, function(item){ return _.contains(array2, item.ID); });
```

You can use [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) and [contains](http://underscorejs.org/#contains).

**Try it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/VVVxH/)!**

Comment: Any other way? I am still not getting my result, it returns empty array.

Comment: I was missing a parenthesis. I added a jsfiddle. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your IDs are unique:

```
var groupedById = _.indexBy(array1, "ID");
var filteredArray = _.map(array2, function (lookupId) {
    return groupedById[lookupId];
});
```

Comment: Note that this will return the items in the same order as the list of IDs you're requesting (i.e., the same order as specified by `array2`). If you would prefer that the ordering in `array1` be preserved, you'll want to use a `_.filter`-based approached.