# Filter array by array Underscore JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'm trying to filter out "Players" by their TeamID which is an array, based on the selected checkboxes in a multi-select ([Bootstrap Multiselect to be precise](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)).

I had it working but the requirements changed and players can be in multiple teams. (I'm sorry I have no JSFiddle / CodePen, Bootstrap Multiselect has no CDN and both of them aren't playing nice)

This is what I had for individual teams which worked.

```
var temp = [];

_.each(selected, function(i){
            temp.push(_.filter(allPlayers, function(obj){
                return obj.TeamID == i;
            }));
});
```

However I need to filter an array by an array.

**JSON**

```
var allPlayers = [{
     "TeamID": [100001, 100002],
     "PlayerID": 1,
     "PlayerName" : "Pete Tong"
    },
    {
     "TeamID": [100001, 100002],
     "PlayerID": 2,
     "PlayerName" : "Will Chamberlain"
    },
    {
     "TeamID": [100002, 100003],
     "PlayerID": 3,
     "PlayerName" : "Jane Doe"
    },
    {
     "TeamID": [100004],
     "PlayerID": 4,
     "PlayerName" : "John Doe"
}];
```

I've tried 
[Filter two different structured arrays underscore js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617600/filter-two-different-structured-arrays-underscore-js)  but it doesn't seem to work for my solution.

**Selected Array**

```
 var teams = $('#team-list option:selected');
 var selected = [];

 $(teams).each(function(index, team){
        selected.push($(this).val());
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use filter(), you don't need an extra outside variable:

```
var allPlayers = [{
     "TeamID": [100001, 100002],
     "PlayerID": 1,
     "PlayerName" : "Pete Tong"
    },
    {
     "TeamID": [100001, 100002],
     "PlayerID": 2,
     "PlayerName" : "Will Chamberlain"
    },
    {
     "TeamID": [100002, 100003],
     "PlayerID": 3,
     "PlayerName" : "Jane Doe"
    },
    {
     "TeamID": [100004],
     "PlayerID": 4,
     "PlayerName" : "John Doe"
}];



var selected=[100003, 100004]; // change this 

var filtered= allPlayers.filter(function(a){
    return selected.some(function(team){
      return a.TeamID.indexOf(team)!==-1;
    });
});

alert(JSON.stringify(filtered, null, "\t"));
```

demo:  http://pagedemos.com/qejbsz722hs3/2

edit: added many to many searching.

Comment: Much cleaner, however I'm afraid to say that `selected` is an array of TeamIDs. This is is what I'm struggling with :)

Comment: @Jezzabeanz: oops, i didn't realize both terms and teams were array-shaped, no problem though, it's still simple and that's a minor adjustment; answer updated.

Comment: It's okay, I should have put that in my code. Ah you're amazing @dandavis, works wonderfully. Would it be weird if I told you I love you?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var temp = [];

_.each(selected, function(i){
            temp.push(_.filter(allPlayers, function(obj){
                return obj.TeamID.indexOf(i) !== -1;
            }));
});
```

Rather than comparing if the TeamID equals the selected id, you can check if the TeamID array contains the selected id.

Comment: Sorry @SlashmanX it doesn't seem to be working. When I output the result of `obj.TeamID.indexOf(i)` everything is `-1`.

Comment: Ah, that could be because you're comparing a string to a number. Is `selected` an array of strings (Seeing as you're using `.val()` to populate it). You could do `....indexOf(parseInt(i, 10))` and see if that works?

Comment: You're right SlashmanX, your solution works too. I wish I could mark both as correct. Sorry buddy, I'm grateful for your time though, so, thank you.